# Lagom: Unable to create injector

Tags: guice, lagom

The error I get is perhaps due to a missing config, incompatible module, ... After a few hours I can't figure it out.

On `sbt runAll`, I get following stack trace:

> com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see
>   the following errors:
>
> 1) Error in custom provider, scala.MatchError: Message (of class
>   sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl)   at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.server.ServiceGuiceSupport.bindServices(ServiceGuiceSupport.java:106)
>   (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>   UserModule)   while locating
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.ResolvedServices
>       for the 2nd parameter of com.lightbend.lagom.internal.server.ServiceRegistrationModule$RegisterWithServiceRegistry.(ServiceRegistrationModule.scala:56)
>   at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.server.ServiceRegistrationModule.bindings(ServiceRegistrationModule.scala:29):
>   Binding(class
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.server.ServiceRegistrationModule$RegisterWithServiceRegistry
>   to self eagerly) (via modules:
>   com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)   while
>   locating
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.server.ServiceRegistrationModule$RegisterWithServiceRegistry
>
> 1 error   at
>   com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:470)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:99)    at
>   com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)     at
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:185)
>     at
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:137)
>     at
>   play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
>     at
>   play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$5(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:176)
>     at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)     at
>   play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$3(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:173)
>     at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)   at
>   play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$2(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:149)
>     at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:247)    at
>   play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$get$1(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:147)
>     at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:655)  at
>   scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:251)  at
>   scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:209)     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:289)  at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:29)     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:29)
>     at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>   Caused by: scala.MatchError: Message (of class
>   sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl)  at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.CallResolver.$anonfun$registeredMessageSerializerFor$1(ServiceCallResolver.scala:46)
>     at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)    at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.CallResolver.registeredMessageSerializerFor(ServiceCallResolver.scala:44)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.CallResolver.messageSerializerFor(ServiceCallResolver.scala:26)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.CallResolver.resolveMessageSerializer(ServiceCallResolver.scala:17)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.ServiceReader$.$anonfun$resolveServiceDescriptor$4(ServiceReader.scala:200)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)  at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)     at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)   at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.ServiceReader$.resolveServiceDescriptor(ServiceReader.scala:158)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder.resolveDescriptor(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:69)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder.$anonfun$resolveServices$1(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:56)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder.resolveServices(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:50)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.ResolvedServicesProvider.get$lzycompute(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:112)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.ResolvedServicesProvider.get(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:111)
>     at
>   com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.ResolvedServicesProvider.get(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:105)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:110)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
>     ... 25 more
>
> Stacktrace caused by project user-impl (filesystem path to project is
>   /Users/kimgysen/Documents/project livefeed/lagom/api-v1/user-impl).
>   Hint: Maybe you have forgot to enable your service Module class via
>   `play.modules.enabled`? (check in your project's application.conf)

My application.conf defines:

```
play.modules.enabled += UserModule
```

- application.conf is stored under user-impl/src/main/resources
- UserModule is stored under user-impl/src/main/java

I followed the available examples for defining my module:

```
public class UserModule extends AbstractModule implements ServiceGuiceSupport {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindService(UserService.class, UserServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

My sbt.build file is very simple as well:

```
organization in ThisBuild := "be.zwoop"
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.12.4"
lagomKafkaEnabled in ThisBuild := true

import scala.concurrent.duration._ // Mind that the import is needed.
lagomCassandraMaxBootWaitingTime in ThisBuild := 50000.seconds

lazy val userApi = project("user-api")
  .settings(
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      lagomJavadslApi,
      lombok
    )
  )

lazy val userImpl = project("user-impl")
  .enablePlugins(LagomJava)
  .settings(
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      lagomJavadslPersistenceCassandra
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(userApi)


val lombok = "org.projectlombok" % "lombok" % "1.16.20"
def project(id: String) = Project(id, base = file(id))
```

I only have 1 plugin defined:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.lagom" % "lagom-sbt-plugin" % "1.4.4")
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Edit how my service looks:

```
public interface UserService extends Service {
    String REGISTER_USER_TOPIC = "users";

    ServiceCall<User, String> registerUser();

    @Override
    default Descriptor descriptor() {
        return named("user").withCalls(
                pathCall("/api/user", this::registerUser)
        ).withPathParamSerializer(
                UUID.class, PathParamSerializers.required("UUID", UUID::fromString, UUID::toString)
        ).withTopics(
                topic(REGISTER_USER_TOPIC, this::UserTopic)
        ).withAutoAcl(true);
    }

    Topic UserTopic();
}
```

Comment: How have you defined `UserService` and `UserServiceImpl`?

Comment: Yes, I've defined them. Extending UserService from `com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.Service` and UserServiceImpl file implements UserService.

Answer (score 0):

The error reporting in Lagom could be improved here, but the problem is that a service call in your `UserService` is using a type variable. For example, you might have something like this in your API:

```
public <Message> ServiceCall<Message, Foo> foo();
```

Essentially, Lagom can't build a service descriptor from that because it doesn't know what type `Message` has.

Comment: This PR should help in identifying errors like this in future: https://github.com/lagom/lagom/pull/1362

Comment: Hm I don't really see it. I've edited my question and added the service definition. I took this from a blog example online. The service takes a User (req) and returns a String (res).

Comment: Hi @Trace, the problem reported in the stackTrace indicates an issue reflectively loading generics information. I think the issue is the missing type information on `Topic UserTopic();`. Try using `Topic<MySomething> UserTopic();`

Comment: @Trace you mentioned "I took this from a blog example online. ", could you share the link to the post?

Comment: @ignasi35 https://github.com/jvz/lagom-example I actually combined a few projects for the demo that I want to achieve. Thanks for your input, the topic was indd the problem; after removing it the error disappeared. I was looking in the wrong place.